# word counting program in c counts more than it should

Tags: c, switch-statement

OK guys, so I wrote this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count words */

main ()
{

    int c, c2;
    long count = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        switch(c)
        {
        case ' ':
        case '\n':
        case '\t':
            switch(c2)
            {
            case ' ':
            case '\n':
            case '\t':
                break;
            default:
                ++count;
            }
        }
        c2 = c;
    }
    printf("Word count: %ld\n", count);
}
```

It counts words from an input, as you can see. So i wrote a file called a-text that only has

```
a text
```

and i wrote in the ubuntu prompt

```
./cw < a-text
```

and it wrote

```
Word count: 2
```

So, what the heck?  Shouldn't it just count 1, because after the second word there's no tab nor new line nor space, only EOF. Why does this happen?

Comment: How are you writing to the file? I just did `printf "a text" > a-text` and your program reports: `Word count: 1`. My guess is that you still may have a new line at the end of your `a-text` file.

Comment: @Th3Cuber no, I opened gedit, wrote "a text" and saved it as a-text. I already checked and there's no new line at the end of the text. I've tried with other files and it always gives the correct word count

Comment: @user2510987 IIRC gedit automatically adds a newline to the end of your text, unless you explicitly disable that feature in the preferences.

Comment: try `od -c a-text`, to see what is in the file. [Word count 2 is correct according to `wc -w`](http://ideone.com/kOokaI)

Comment: "I already checked" -- Checked how?

Comment: Note that your program has undefined behavior if the file starts with `' '`, `'\n'`, or `'\t'`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not count words rather than spaces? Then you don't have a problem when the input ends with space.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    int was_space = 1;
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        count += !isspace(c) && was_space;
        was_space = isspace(c);
    }
    printf("Word count: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lets see what happens with "a text"

```
after the first iteration, c2 == 'a', count remains 0
now comes c == ' ' c2 is still 'a', so count == 1, c2 becomes == ' '
now comes c == 't' c2 is still ' '. so count remains == 1
...
now comes c == '\n' c2 is the last 't'. count becomes == 2
```

IOW

```
"a text\n"
  ^----^-------- count == 1
       |
       +-------- count == 2
```

Comment: but why is there a \n at the if it is a text file? Or do all text files end with \n?

Comment: @user2510987 Why wouldn't there be a \n at the end? \n signifies the end of a line, and a text file usually consists of lines.

Comment: @user2510987 it depends on how you created the file, if you wrote the line and pressed ENTER at the end of the line before closing it there will be a \n at the end